# Git Ignored files are reverting to original state

Tags: git

I have a configuration file ignored via:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt
```

I allow users to update this configuration file. Somehow after I merge branches the file gets reverted to the original state  Does anyone know if I a missing something?  Weird thing is that it doesn't always happen so it's hard to replicate.

Here is an example workflow with branch called 1100:

1. git checkout -b 1100
2. Make code changes
3. git add filename
4. git commit -m '#1100 code update' (sometime I do a git commit -am '#1100 code update')
5. git push origin 1100
6. on dev server git checkout -b 1100
7. git pull origin 1100
8. Now go back to local and do git checkout master
9. git merge 1100
10. git push

Comment: Do you have any flags set when you merge, or do you have non-standard merge options enabled by default?

Comment: Hmm not even sure how to check this. I only do a regular git merge.

Comment: Alright then you are probably fine on that count.  Can you edit your post to include an example of how you are merging or your general workflow involved in this situation?

Comment: Added workflow to my post.

Comment: Wait, in step 2 "Make code changes" are you actually committing anything?

Comment: Sorry forgot that in my workflow. Updated workflow step.

Comment: Could you run `git ls-files -v` at various stages in your workflow to check if the `--assume-unchanged` flag is still set for this file?

Answer (score 1):

The “assume unchanged” bit is stored in the index, but it is not recorded in the tree associated with a commit.  If you push some changes and check them out on a different machine, the bit in the index on this machine will not be updated.